# CSS Slide menu does not work as expected

Tags: html, css

here is my situation:

I've created this slide menu: 
http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/vgBmGG

It is working fine and i like it.

**The problem happens in the live version, when I tried to add it to my web app, simply it is not responding to the click.**

I haven't hosted my app yet and I think it would be too much code to put it all here, but I have my github repo as public.

If you want to check it out, well you will know of course, `npm install` and then `npm start`

It is a ReactJS project + CSS, the component, which is not working as I expect is called ThemeSelector. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/flarocca/web.facundolarocca.com/blob/NewStyle/src/components/ThemeSelector.js)

I'm adding it into [this one](https://github.com/flarocca/web.facundolarocca.com/blob/NewStyle/src/components/App.js), check line 42.

All CSS classes can be found [here](https://github.com/flarocca/web.facundolarocca.com/blob/NewStyle/src/css/App.css)

Whatever you think that is needed to clarify my problem, let my know!!

Thanks in advance and **HAPPY NEW YEAR** for everybody!!!!

### **Edited after @Gaby aka G. Petrioli's answer**

As I'm using ReactJS instead of pure HTML, `for` tag must be replaced with `htmlFor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to add the `for="navigation"` on the [`label` <sup>line 22</sup>](https://github.com/flarocca/web.facundolarocca.com/blob/NewStyle/src/components/ThemeSelector.js#L22), so they are not linked.